# How to activate key-fob with new battery, Nissan Murano

Tags: smartkey

The original key-fob battery died for my 2011 Nissan Murano , the second fob works fine. I got new battery ( Rayovac 2032 lithium). Put it in - no action. Read the manual ; The fob battery instructions are one sentence-" When the battery is discharged , replace it ". There are 6 pages with figures on how to push the 4 buttons on the fob. Opened the fob again - there is only one way the battery fits ( so polarity  is OK) , I gently, slightly sprung the contacts toward the battery ; Closed it , still no action .....If there was some program necessary to activate it ,I would expect the manual to have info. The Dealer is about 70 miles away so I do not want to make that trip. I used to be on the Murano Forum but I am old and can not get through the fire-wall after not using it for a few years.

Comment: As I understand it, you don't register the car to the key fob, but rather the key fob to the car. This means the car should remember the key fob even if the battery has gone south and you've replaced it. The car should recognize the fob and shouldn't need re-initializing. I'd suggest you are having an issue with the fob itself. Either it is broken and no longer works or the car has lost it. Many auto parts stores have readers which can tell if your fob is working or not. You press the button on your fob and the lights on the reader respond. You might give this a try to further diagnose.

Comment: The car does remember the fob. When the battery was dead I put the fob into the dashboard slot and the car ran , that is how I got to the store to buy a battery.

Comment: I am so embarrassed; I opened the second fob and saw I had put the battery in upside down . What I thought was a stop was actually a clip that holds the battery in place, you push the battery past it, everything is fine .  So at 73,000 miles no problem or service ever needed ( except oil change, tires, etc.).